# Error when trying to select data from a database stored in phpmyadmin using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Can someone please show me where is the error in this code because i'm trying to selct data from a database i've created in phpmyadmin but the output is:Notice: Undefined variable: POST in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\browsestudents.php on line 25.
The database works correctly.This is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Online Jobs 
 </title>

</head>
<body>

<form action="browsestudents.php" method="POST">
<?php
print("Kerko studentet ne varesi te pozicionit te aplikuar te punes:
 <form><select name='position'>
<option value='it'>IT</option>
<option value='a'>a</option>
<option value='b'>b</option>
        </select>
        <input type='submit' value='Search'/>
      </form>");

if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )
   print("Could not connect");


if(isset($_POST['position'])&&!empty($_POST['position'])){
 $position=$POST['position'];
 if($position=='a'||$position=='b'||$position=='it')
 {
$query="SELECT `firstname`,`lastname`,`cv`,`position` /*shto listene notave ne fund*/
FROM `login`
 WHERE `position`='$position' /*AND food LIKE 'P%' */
 ORDER BY `id`";


 if($result=mysql_query($query,$database))
 {

  if(mysql_num_rows($result)==NULL){//nr i rreshtave te query qe kemi kerkuar esht NULL
echo"no result found";
 }
else

 while($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))//krijon nje vektor 
 //query_row te cilit i asocion te dhenat e query
{
$firstname=$query_row["firstname"];//query_row esht vektor associativ qe i vendoset vlera e food
$lastname=$query_row["lastname"];
$cv=$query_row["cv"];
$position=$query_row["position"];
echo $firstname."<br/> Here is his cv".$cv."and position".$position;
}



 }
 else
 echo mysql_error();

}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 25 you have **$POST** instead of **$_POST** which would be the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

```
$position=$POST['position'];
```

There should be an underscore `_` between `$` and `POST`.

Learn yourself to read the errors. *Notice: Undefined variable: POST in ... on line 25.* So go to line 25 and try to find out what's wrong...

Comment: Of course i know how to read comments but so tired i can't even notice this error.Thanks